# FolderClosedException while constructing an MimeMessage

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, mime

I have an application where I'm reading emails from mailbox and converting it into MimeMessage for further processing.
However I'm getting an exception when the mail contains large attachment of around 40Mb. Below is the code I'm using.

```java
Message[] messages = null;
Folder folder = emailServerConnection.getFolder();
messages = folder.getMessages();
List<Email> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Message message : messages)
{
    try
    {
        //Below line throwing FolderClosedException
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage((MimeMessage) message); 
        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mimeMessage.writeTo(outputStream);
        JavaMailEmail email = new JavaMailEmail(mimeMessage, message);
        messageList.add(email);
    }
    catch (MessagingException ex)
    {
        _loggingHelper.debug(ex, "Problem reading an email. Marking it as an email to delete.");
        message.setFlag(Flag.DELETED, true);
    }
}
```

The issue occurs only if my email has large attachment(40 Mb)

```
Exception:
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while copying message;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.util.FolderClosedIOException
```

Any help or pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: Too vague to reproduce or consider, I'm afraid...

Comment: @arnt I have updated the the question, Is it understandable now ?

Comment: No. At least you need the exception too.

Comment: What are the versions of Java and Java mail?